# Warning in a stylesheet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

How to solve while writing the code that show Warnings

Everything works.. except warning for the code shown below.

```
*@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {right: 0px;}
    to {right: 500px;}
}*
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Using px after 0 is not needed and results in warnings in some IDEs. Try changing 0px to just 0.